# python change random time index to second base index

Tags: python, pandas

I have quite some difficulties formulating the question hence please find an example below:
I have:

```
2017-11-23 16:30:52+01:00  20
2017-11-23 16:30:58+01:00  30
2017-11-23 16:31:30+01:00  25
```

I would like to have:

```
2017-11-23 16:30:52+01:00  20
2017-11-23 16:30:53+01:00  20
2017-11-23 16:30:54+01:00  20
...
2017-11-23 16:30:58+01:00  30
2017-11-23 16:30:59+01:00  30
...
```

Actually, I thought this would be an easy job using pandas resample with pad

```
df=df.resample('1s').pad()
```

However, this returns the following:

```
2017-11-23 16:30:52+01:00  20
2017-11-23 16:30:53+01:00  NaN
2017-11-23 16:30:54+01:00  NaN
...
2017-11-23 16:30:58+01:00  NaN
2017-11-23 16:30:59+01:00  NaN
...
```

The column is of type (float64)..

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if somebody phase the same problem.. you have to use pandas.interpolate. [Pandas interpolate doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

Comment: Are original data confidental?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use `fillna` after `resample`

```
df=df.resample('1s').fillna(method = 'pad')
```

`resample` will create rows with 1s separation on pandas datetime index, and will fill values for the indexes it is available. You need to fill it for rest of the rows. There `fillna` method can be used. `method='pad'` fills all the values with last non null value.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.